# setting active profile defined in parent pom in project pom

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

We have a corporate wide *Super Pom* we use to define many of the defaults we use. For example, the *Super Pom* defines what version of the JDK to use, and other parameters. This is inherited by our projects as the parent pom.

Most of our projects use JDK 1.7, but one set of projects is still on version JDK 1.6. I've put the following profile definitions in my parent pom:

```
<properties>
    <travelclick.snapshot.repo>artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</travelclick.snapshot.repo>
    <old.javac.source>1.5</old.javac.source>
    <old.javac.target>1.6</old.javac.target>
</properties>
<profiles>
    ...
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.6</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <...>
                        <source>${old.javac.source}</source>
                        <target>${old.javac.target}</target>
                        <...>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <...>
</profiles>
```

Now, I have a profile called `jdk1.6` and I'd like to specify in the project's pom that it should use this one by default. How do I do this?

I've tried adding into the project's pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.6</id>
        <activations>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activations>
    </profile>
</profile>
```

But that redefines my jdk1.6 profile.

I've tried putting in this:

```
<activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>jdk1.6</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

But that only works in `settings.xml`.

How do I specify a profile in the parent pom, and then say that this is the active profile in the child pom?

---

## More Attempts

I've tried using properties. In my parent pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.6</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>use-jdk1.6</name>
            </property>
       </activation>
   <profile>
</profiles>
```

And the following in my local pom:

```
<properties>
     <use-jdk1.6>true</use-jdk1.6>
</properties>
```

But, it doesn't pick up the profile. And, this does work:

```
$ mvn -Puse-jdk1.6 clean package site
```

So, I know that the parent profiles do work.

---

## Profiles

> Could you add yours profile details exectuing goal help:all-profiles

```
[INFO] Listing Profiles for Project: xxxx
  Profile Id: artifactory (Active: true , Source: settings.xml)
  Profile Id: jdk1.6 (Active: false , Source: pom)
  Profile Id: arse-version (Active: false , Source: pom)
  Profile Id: urge (Active: false , Source: pom)
```

I can activate jdk1.6 from the command line. I just want to activate it as the default in my child poms.

Comment: Do you have to use a profile? If you just want to override the JDK used, use a Maven property like `javac.source` for the `source` and `javac.target` for the `target` of the `maven-compiler-plugin`. Then you can let the child POM define the two properties when they need different one than the default, (that the parent would set to `1.7`).

Comment: I think you are complicating your situation by adding a profile. If your goal is to compile those projects with a different jdk than the one mentioned in the super pom, then let your child project override the compiler version in its pom. Did you try doing this ?

Comment: could you add yours profile details exectuing goal help:all-profiles?

Comment: Yes, I defined a `<plugin>` with `maven-compiler-plugin` in my child poms. This adds some complexity and a lot of duplication between poms. I thought taking care of this problem via the parent pom will make it simpler.

Answer (score 3):

## AAAAHGGGGHHHH!

That's me screaming.

I found the issue and why this wasn't working.

In my parent pom, I had the following:

```
<properties>
    <javac.source>1.7</javac.source>
    <javac.source>1.7</javac.source>
    <old.javac.source>1.7</old.javac.source>
    <old.javac.source>1.7</old.javac.source>
    ...
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk1.6</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
               <name>use-jdk1.6</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
        <plugins>
           ....
           <plugin>
                 <groupId>maven-compiler-plugin</groupId>
                 ...
                 <configuration>
                     <!-- This isn't doing what I think -->
                     <source>${old.javac.source}</source>
                     <target>${old.javac.target}</source>
                     ...
                 </configuration>
           </plugin>
      </plugins>
<profile>
```

In my child pom, I had this:

```
 <properties>
     <use-jdk1.6>true</use-jdk1.6>
</properties>
```

And, it appeared that setting the `use-jdk1.6` property just wasn't working. However, that wasn't the case. I was setting the profile.

What happens is if I have the system property `javac.source` and `javac.target` set, it overrides the configuration of the `maven-compiler-pluing` (even though I had explicitly set `<source>` and `<target>` not to use version 1.7).

So, I spent six hours on this issue before I realized it was due to me setting a property named `javac.source` rather than something like `java-version`.